# Can I fill multiple form feilds in an PDF with the same data automatically?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, adobe-indesign

I am creating a form in Indesign CS6 for filling out in Acrobat. Its a tenancy agreement it requires names and addresses to be input 2-3 times. Is there a way to link the form fields in Indesign or in Acrobat Pro so that they all fill out together?

Comment: @chris but that is the answer I figured out its not additional information on the question